# Google Cloud free credit discrepancy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to keep track of Google Cloud credits remaining. After just sign up it shows that you have ended your free trial and after upgrading it shows no credits to show in Billing Section. Do I run out of my $300 credits?

Answer (score 5):

Billing > Overview > "Billing Account Overview" section is the location from where you supposed to see the remaining free credit from your Cloud Console. You may not get Google Cloud Platform Free Tier if you are not eligible. This [article](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial-eligibility) is helpful to find who is eligible. You can go to [Transaction](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-history) tab from the billing to see how your free trial was charged provided you were eligible and successfully opt-in for the free trial.

If you upgrade to a paid account before the 12-month trial period ends, any remaining amount of your initial $300 credit remains in your account. This credit expires after 12 months, when your free trial period would have originally ended. Any charges you incur between your upgrade and the expiration of the free-trial credit are billed first against the credit.

As you mentioned, you signed up for a free trial and your credit ended without using it, you can file your query to [Google Cloud Platform Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) team.